# Cannot connect via SSH when using password. Password incorrect error, even though password is correct

Tags: debian, ssh, maemo

I'm using Maemo on my Nokia N900. It's basically Debian Lenny. It's running OpenSSH 5.1p1.

I'm trying to connect to the phone via SSH. I have it connected to the computer, and I can ping the IP address and attempt an SSH connection. The problem is I can not log in with the user password.

I do the following from my machine:

```
ssh root@192.168.2.17 (this is the phone's IP)
```

I get asked for the password and enter it. It returns with password incorrect after 3 attempts.

I have tried to reset the password using `passwd` and `passwd root`. I can successfully change the password. I've rebooted sshd, and the phone, to no avail.

On the phone, if I run `ssh root@localhost` it asks for the password and works fine. But doesn't seem to work if I try to login from my machine. The IP is definitely correct and is the correct device.

Is there any reason why this may not be working?

Here's the output when I try connect:

```
ssh root@192.168.2.17
The authenticity of host '192.168.2.17 (192.168.2.17)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:0AnEm/7SPc9ELe7ZGXacXeVVKjbpSsADNPSx0Fay45Y.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.2.17' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
Password:
Password:
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ... `PermitRootLogin` is set to yes (I know this is bad, but this is a dummy phone for local use only). `RSAAuthentication` and `PublicKeyAuthentication` are both set to `yes`.

After running `sh -v -v root@192.168.2.17`:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
```

Comment: I don't suppose you have any `AllowUsers` directives in `sshd_config` either? Try the connection with more verbosity: `ssh -v -v root@192.168.2.17` and also see if `/var/log/auth.log` has anything.

Comment: watch maemo:/var/log/auth.log and daemon.log for details, or run sshd in debug mode: `/usr/sbin/sshd -D -d`

Comment: @ilkkachu added the output when using `-v -v`. No `AllowUsers` directives.

Comment: @IporSircer I don't have those log files. Will run a find.

Comment: I don't know if I'm editing the correct config file, but I've turned off RSAAuth by setting to no in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and restarted, but upon login I get: `Offering RSA public key: /Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: @IporSircer tried running in debug mode. I turn ssh off using `/etc/init.d/ssh stop` and then ran the command you suggested. No logs showed that I attempted a login. I stopped that, and tried to log in via SSH and I'm getting a prompt. Confused because it should have been off. But if I turn the nokia off, no connection. It almost looks like the wrong IP address, but it isn't.

Comment: Oh wait, now something is going on. I ran nmap on the IP and get `22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 6.9 (protocol 2.0)` ... thats not right I'm using 5.1. So confused!

Comment: That is why full log would be helpful. The log contains versions of both client and server. All the time connecting to some different device? Also 5.1 does not certainly support ECDSA keys.

Comment: Post the complete content of `sshd_config`. That file might allow password logins only if they're local.